# go 1.5 cross compile using cgo on OS X to linux and windows

Tags: go, cross-compiling, libgit2, cgo, gccgo

I'm having trouble compiling the [`git2go`](https://github.com/libgit2/git2go) library on OS X to linux amd64 after upgrading go 1.4.2 to go 1.5.

I think this is about cross compiling any go app that uses C code with go 1.5.

Using `CGO_ENABLED=1`, I get:

```sh
$ CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 ./script/with-static.sh go install ./...
# runtime/cgo
ld: unknown option: --build-id=none
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Using `-compiler=gccgo`, I get:

```sh
$ GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 ./script/with-static.sh go install -compiler gccgo ./...
go build github.com/libgit2/git2go: : fork/exec : no such file or directory
```

If not supplying any of those, I get:

```sh
$ GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 ./script/with-static.sh go install ./...
can't load package: package github.com/libgit2/git2go: C source files not allowed when not using cgo or SWIG: wrapper.c
```

I installed go using homebrew, and I have the `$GOPATH` pointing to the default `~/go` location, nothing fancy.

Comment: Setting up arch linux on qemu or virtualbox should be trivial to compile for linux, and you can follow *my* [guide](http://www.limitlessfx.com/cross-compile-golang-app-for-windows-from-linux.html) to cross-compile from there to windows.

Comment: You probably want to skip up to the last compile step if you're using 1.5.

Comment: @OneOfOne your comment helped alot, it's fairly easy to cross compile for Windows from a Linux container. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

cgo is not enabled by default when cross compiling. If you enable cgo, with CGO_ENABLED=1 you will need to have a cross compiling c compiler for the target machine. This is non trivial.

I recommend, if you need cgo, to compile natively.

Answer (score 1):

If you need cgo cross compilation, I'd point you to [xgo](https://github.com/karalabe/xgo), which I found immensely helpful. It didn't work in 100% of my use cases, but with some minor (compared to maintaining native VMs for cross-compiling) changes to my code, it was sufficient.

Comment: A maintained version https://github.com/crazy-max/xgo